How do you interpret $G(x)$ in the Fundamental Theorem of calculus?
So the Fundamental theorem of Calculus states that
If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then we can define a function $G(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt$ and this function will give us the value of the area under $f$ from $a$ to $x$. Then $\frac{dG}{dx}=f(x)$.
Now $f(x)$ has many derivatives each of which differs from $G(x)$ by a constant, so $G(x)=F(x)+C$.
So a unique thing about $G(x)$ is that it tracks the area under $f(x)$ exactly while other anti-derivatives do not have this ability as they are always off by a constant. But could we make an argument that for any antiderivative $F$ of $f$ there exists a lower bound $a$ of the integral $\int_a^xf(t)dt$ such that $F$ happens to calculate the area under $f$ from $a$ exactly because of the fact that $F(a)=0$ for that particular $a$ that we chose. So basically any antiderivative $F$ can be defined as $\int_a^xf(t)dt$ if we choose the right $a$ such that $F(a)=0$.I'm asking this because differentiation and integration are said to be reverse operations, but they are only reverse up to the point where you start calculating the area under $f$.

I believe that such a function $F$ would have to contain two variables. One of which being $x$ and the other being your specified $a$. It makes more sense and is more simple notationally speaking to simply say that, for any such antiderivative $F$, the area under the curve will always be $F(x)-F(a)$ as a consequence of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

This reads like your treatise, not like a question. Please clarify your question, if you have one.


But could we make an argument that for any antiderivative $F$ of $f$ there exists a lower bound $a$ of the integral $\int_a^xf(t)dt$ such that $F$ happens to calculate the area under $f$ from $a$ exactly because of the fact that $F(a)=0$ for that particular $a$ that we chose. So basically any antiderivative $F$ can be defined as $\int_a^xf(t)dt$ if we choose the right $a$ such that $F(a)=0$.

No, because not every antiderivative of $f$ will even have a zero. Consider $f(x) = 2x$. Then $F(x) = x^2 + 1$ is an antiderivative for $f$. But there isn't any $a$ such that $\int_a^x 2t\,dt = x^2 + 1$, because the left-hand side equals $x^2-a^2$, and $x^2-a^2 = x^2 + 1$ doesn't have a real solution.
